# How can I change color for HTML5 progress bar control for Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, progress-bar

I have an HTML5 progress bar. I am trying to change its color to blue. The color changes in IE but not in Chrome.

I did look in other forums, coped styles from there but so far the progress color doesn't change. How should update my CSS to change progress bar color for Chrome?

```
/* IE10 */
progress {
    color: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Chrome */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Polyfill */
progress[aria-valuenow]:before {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

progress {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: blue;
}

progress[value] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Looks blue to me...perhaps you could clarify what **specifically** should be blue but isn't?

Comment: Your code seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code definitely works, however, I'm assuming that Chrome cached your CSS that's why you don't see changes while you do in Internet Explorer. It happens pretty often, so in order to tackle this annoying issue, you can simply reload the page in the Chrome with a shortcut F5 (Windows) or CMD + R (Mac). If that doesn't help, try hard reload with a shortcut CTRL + F5 (Windows) or CMD + SHIFT + R (Mac). Also, the alternative would be going via incognito mode. In that case, the changes should be visible.

Comment: No problem at all @Mikhail! Glad that I helped you out! If you don't mind please accept this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out by @Kornelijus Glinskas, I did indeed worked with the cached CSS, after I pressed CNTRL-F5, the color appeared. However, the colors weren't adequate as both the progress bar and its background were the same color. Here I [post the final CSS

```
/* IE10 */
progress {
    color: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Chrome */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

/* Polyfill */
progress[aria-valuenow]:before {
    background: blue;
    border: solid 1pt gray;
    width: 300pt;
    height: 20px;
}

progress {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}

progress[value] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `accent-color` property, made for that purpose. It also applies to  radio/checkboxes. PS Chrome will automatically change the background to get high enough contrst.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color